# Python : Clean and efficient way to remove items that are not convertable to int from list

Tags: python, list, python-2.7, integer

I have a list like this:

```
mylist = [1.0,2.0,3.0,4.0,...,u'*52', u'14*', u'16*',"", "" ,"",...]
```

It basically contains, `float`, `unicodes` and `blank(string?)`. (It could have other data types as well)

My objective is to remove any item which are not convertible to integer from the list.

I have tried using `.isdigit()` like this:

```
newlist= [i for i in mylist if i.isdigit()]
```

but I ended up having `AttributeError`:

```
AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'isdigit'
```

What would be a clean and neat way (without using too many if/else or try/except clauses) to achieve this?

I am using python 2.7

Comment: are the floats actually all  floats  or strings?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham they are actual floats

Comment: @ChrisAung,  yes, I copped that when I looked at the error traceback, time for a coffee I think!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could use a helper function:

```
def convertible(v):
    try:
        int(v)
        return True
    except (TypeError, ValueError):
        return False

newlist = [i for i in mylist if convertible(i)]
```

Comment: Why do we need to catch the `TypeError` and `ValueError`? Why can't i just do something like " convert to integer if it can't be done, ignore)"

Comment: Because in other situations you want to be told you made a mistake and tried to convert something you cannot convert.

Answer (score 3):

```
from numbers import Number

mylist = [1.0,2.0,3.0,4.0,u'*52', u'14*', u'16*',"", "" ,""]

mylist[:] = [ele for ele in mylist if isinstance(ele,Number)]

print(mylist)
```

Why you get the `AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'isdigit'` is because `isdigit` is a str method, you are trying to call it on an actual float.

`mylist[:]` changes the original list which may or may not be what you want, if you want to keep both just use `newlist= ...`.

Answer (score 2):

For Your example list this can apply, "without using too many if/else or try/except clauses"

```
>>>[i for i in mylist if isinstance(i, (int, float))]
[1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code:

```
mylist = [1.0,2.0,3.0,4.0,u'*52', u'14*', u'16*']
newlst=[]
for i in mylist:
    try:
        newlst.append(int(i))
    except ValueError:

        pass
print newlst
```

Comment: Although the code is appreciated, it should always have an accompanying explanation. This doesn't have to be long but it is expected.