# How to separate data types from list?

Tags: python

I'm having trouble trying to separate string and int/float from a single array. So far I could only find methods to remove/extract from list with specific string or number but not datatypes :(

Input:

```
a = [1,2,3,'a',4,11,212,'a','b','c',3,32,4,'d','e']
```

Desired output:

```
['a','a','b','c','d','e']
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python : Clean and efficient way to remove items that are not convertable to int from list](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29913324/python-clean-and-efficient-way-to-remove-items-that-are-not-convertable-to-int)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Python has the [isinstance()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#isinstance) function to check if objects are of given type.
Btw your given list is not correct !

```
>>> l = [1, 2, 3, 'a', 4, 11, 212, 'a', 'b', 'c', 3, 32, 4, 'd', 'e']
>>> [item for item in l if isinstance(item, str)]
['a', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']
```

Comment: I've edited the post. Thanks for the help! still new to python. Haha

Comment: One additional question if you don't mind. If l is declared as np.array(), then the code does not work as all elements in the array is string type. 

Is there a way around this?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`type()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#type) function to distinguish between the different data types.

Comment: @Craicerjack Thanks, added

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
a = [1,2,3,'a',4,11,212,'a','b','c',3,32,4,'d','e']
[x for x in a if type(x)==str]
```

Output is:

```
['a', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']
```

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to achieve this scenario, You can use idiomatic way too,

```
a = [1,2,3,'a',4,11,212,'a','b','c',3,32,4,'d','e']

print [item for item in a if type(item) is str]

Output list: ['a', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']
```