# How to remove a specific data type from a list

Tags: python, string, list, floating-point, integer

A list can be made of different data types. So how can l separate the data types like storing the integers in their own list and strings in their own list or even floats. A list like
name = ["king",'data',22,33,2.5,3.5]
l need some code that will be able lets say to add strings from the name list to a new empty list

Comment: Hi there Forbearance! Have you seen https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41828792/how-to-separate-data-types-from-list?

Comment: If possible, fix the situation that can create a heterogenous list in the first place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

are you looking for this

```
names = ["king",'data',22,33,2.5,3.5]
l = [n for n in names if isinstance(n, str)]
```

Output:

```
['king', 'data']
```

Comment: you could add "str" as variable and dependig of what the need could  separete int or str

Answer (score 0):

You can check for a given datatype with isinstance() method:

```
lst = ["king", "data", 22, 33, 2.5, 3.5]

f = []
s = []
i = []
o = []

# for each item in the list
for item in lst:
    # if an item is a string
    if isinstance(item, str):
        # append the item to s list
        s.append(item)
    elif isinstance(item, int):
        i.append(item)
    elif isinstance(item, float):
        f.append(item)
    else:
        o.append(item)
    
print(f, s, i)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
name = ["king",'data',22,33,2.5,3.5]
str_list = []
num_lists = []

for elem in name:
    if type(elem) == str:
        str_list.append(elem)
    elif type(elem) == int:
        num_lists.append(elem)
        
        
print(name)
print(str_list)
print(num_lists)
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
from collections import defaultdict
input_list = ["king", 'data', 22, 33, 2.5, 3.5] 
d = defaultdict(list)
for v in input_list:
    d[type(v)].append(v)
```

For example, if you only need strings:

```
strings = d[str]  # ['king', 'data']
```